# Call servlet without form

Tags: html, servlet-3.0

Here is my code for a submit button in html without form.
 `<a href="/LoginService"><button type="submit" class="submit">Sign In</button></a>`
/LoginService is the annotation i used for my servlet. This isn't working. I would like to know where to set the "post" or "get" method and also the correct format to set this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can fire an ajax call in some java script function. Declare a xmlhttprequest object and specify get or post and servlet to call.

```
    asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", stateChange, false);
    asyncRequest.open('GET', '/Test', true);    //   /Test is url to Servlet!
    asyncRequest.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suspect this is because you are not enclosing with a form tag... That is why they are not accessible.

The best possible way i can think of is add data in json and trigger an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to servlet by removing '/' before servlet name in the code. However i can't get any data from html. I'm getting a null pointer exception in the servlet.

I added a form and removed the hyperlink from the button. That solved it. Thankyou for helping me.